# Not able get the return value of command print os.path.isfile(filename) from with in paramiko connection

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to a machine and if that fails I try a different machine and so on. Once I am connected I check for certain file. If that file is inside I do the processing with it. If not and I get out of that machine and try to connect to a different machine and check for the file.

Now in my below code I need to know how could I get the return value of the command `print os.path.isfile(file)` that is executed on the remote machine?

```
for machine in file1_ips:
    try:
       conn = ssh.connect(machine,
                          username="root",
                          allow_agent=True,
                          look_for_keys=False
                          )
       if conn is None:
          print machine +" " + "Successfully Authenticated\n"
          print "DB shared file exists\n"
          stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('print os.path.isfile("r/a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared")')
          #rval =  stdout.read()
          #print rval

          print stdout ##I need something like "True"

          stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("cat /a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared")
          data = stdout.read()
          print data
          pswd_line = pswd.findall(data)
          if pswd_line:
             print data
          ssh.close()
       break

    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print "Authentication failed\n"
```

Right now I get the output in below formate:

```
192.168.24.71 Successfully Authenticated

<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x8368410L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>

AIMS_PASS=wreretet
ASAPMSTR_PASS=dfdgdg
CREP_PASS=gfhfh
DSS_PASS=dgfhhfh
ELS_PASS=Rdgdh
EXTAPI_PASS=qadgdbbc
```

Comment: Should't you put shell code in `exec_command`? what about `if [ -f "/a/b/c" ]; then echo "true"; fi` so you do not load python on the other end

Comment: I did somewhat similar but didn't work. # stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls -al /a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared:echo $?")
                # print stdout.read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're passing Python over SSH, when you should be using a shell command:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('print os.path.isfile("r/a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared")')
```

Try this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("""python -c 'import os; print os.path.isfile("r/a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared")'""")
```

For what it's worth, this doesn't seem to be the right way to do this - you should probably use a shell command that returns a non-zero exit status if the file doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
ssh.exec_command('ls r/a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared')

if ssh.recv_exit_status() == 0:
    # file exists
else:
    # file does not exist
```

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/skandasa/PycharmProjects/ds/projectPassword.py", line 84, in <module>
    file_exists = ssh.exec_command('ls r/a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared').recv_exit_status()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recv_exit_status''

Comment: Does 'recv_exit_status()' come along with `paramiko`. I am not sure.

Comment: I tried this after your suggestion, but it didn't work as well. # stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls -al /a/etc/portal/db/secrets/db.shared:echo $?")
                # print stdout.read()

Comment: Ah - I'm just now looking at this. `recv_exit_status()` is a method of `ssh`, not of the returned tuple. My bad. I'll update the suggestion. That's what I get for writing code in the browser window :)